# Run VBS script with privileges on computer startup / log in

Tags: windows, windows-10, script, vbscript

I have `script.vbs` that I want to run on computer startup, after login to Windows.

Tried to place it in startup directory -> doesn't work.

Tried to select this in Windows's task scheduler -> doesn't work.

What does `doesn't work` mean? I means that instead of running it, it opens in text editor.

I have read that Windows 10 doesn't allow to run scripts like that (`vbs`, `ps1`) directly, especially on startup

I made workaround by startuping `cmd` that starts `vbs` or `ps1`. But I don't like that. Cuz it always opens for a second a window...

So

How to run directly `vbs` on windows startup?

---

Having

Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Run it using `wscript.exe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting the script itself in the startup folder, put a batch file (`.bat`)
containing the [cscript command](https://ss64.com/vb/cscript.html) like this:

```
cscript //nologo \path\to\script.vbs > nul
```

Where :

- `//nologo` is to hide the startup logo
- `> nul` is for not generating output.